# SP2019 Management Shell showing error for a Farm account

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

On a single server farm, I am trying to run SP19 management shell as admin and before running any script, it shows below:
[image]

Can someone please assist what could be wrong here?perhaps help with me with a solution please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're not running the shell 'As Administrator'. If you were, the title bar of the shell would show "Administrator: SharePoint 2019 Management Shell".

Answer (score 1):

The only person that came help you with SPShell admin level access is another user who is already a SPShell admin.

If you are not having enough privileges and you try to get yourself added as an SPShell admin that won't work .

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command and then check it.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

Add-SPShellAdmin -username DOMAIN\SPAdmin
```

Alternatively, try disabling UAC by following [this](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/12/how-to-disable-uac-in-windows-server-2012.html?m=1) article.

Comment: Getting "You need to have Machine administrator priviliges to run this cmdlet."

Comment: Are you running the management shell as admin? Screenshot does not suggest so

Comment: I did right click and ran as admin

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following privileges and your error will get sorted out .

1. Security admin server role on SQL server instance
2. db_owner on Configuration database ,Admin content database and the content database on which you are intending to run this cmdlet .
3. You must be a local administrator on the local machine

Once you have these privileges run the Add-SPShellAdmin cmdlet and let yourself get added .

Your error will vanish after this.